# Kivy does not load ff_mpeg

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, kivy, pyglet

I have been trying to use a simple code to play videos with Kivy and Python. The shortest code I found is the one shown below.

1. At first, Kivy was showing an error on `Pyglet` and `ff_mpeg`. Therefore, I installed Pyglet - which consequently require `AVbin`, - none of which would load automatically.
2. I found the following solution on another post - which fixed the sound:

   ```
   import pyglet
   pyglet.lib.load_library('avbin')
   pyglet.have_avbin=True
   ```
3. Can I do the same with `ff_mpeg`? Can it be loaded manually?
4. I have already installed `ffmpeg` :

   - When I type `ffmpeg -version` on cmd - it displays ffmpeg version N-....      built with gcc 4.9.2(GCC). Also, I have added all the paths in WIndows.
5. Also my `pip list`:

   ```
   Cython (0.21.2)
   docutils (0.12)
   ffmpegwrapper (0.1.dev0)
   Kivy (1.8.0)
   Kivy-Garden (0.1.1)
   Pillow (2.1.0)
   pip (6.0.8)
   pygame (1.9.2a0)
   pyglet (1.2.1)
   requests (2.5.1)
   setuptools (12.0.5)
   ```
6. Error on Kivy:

   ```
   [DEBUG      ] [Video     ] Ignored <ffmpeg> (import error)
   [INFO       ] [Video     ] Provider: pyglet(['video_ffmpeg'] ignored)
   ```

   and

   ```
   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\video\video_pyglet.py", line   67, in _update
      self._player.dispatch_events(dt)
   AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'dispatch_events'
   ```
7. And, finally here is the code - I am working with:

   ```
   import kivy
   import pyglet
   pyglet.lib.load_library('avbin')
   pyglet.have_avbin=True

   kivy.require('1.8.0')

   from sys import argv
   from os.path import dirname, join
   from kivy.app import App
   from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer

   class VideoPlayerApp(App):

       def build(self):
           if len(argv) > 1:
               filename = argv[1]
           else:
               curdir = dirname(__file__)
               filename = join(curdir, 'project.mp4')
           return VideoPlayer(source=filename, state='play')

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       VideoPlayerApp().run()
   ```

I have searched a lot of other threads, and installed ffmpeg several times with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The provider "ffmpeg" is not using the installed ffmpeg at all. Read the header of the backend at: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/video/video_ffmpeg.py

As for pyglet, if it doesn't work, we can't really help for it, it's more up to the pyglet installation itself.

Our integrated player is based on GStreamer, which is your best bet for Desktop (named gstplayer).

To resume:

- On desktop, use our packages, and gstplayer-based backend will be used.
- On iOS, build the toolchain with ffpyplayer, and you'll have an ffmpeg-based player available.
- On Android, build the toolchain with ffmpeg, and you'll have a ffmpeg-based player as well.

Comment: 'On desktop, use our packages, and gstplayer-based backend will be used.' - can you add some steps for this - i am still very new at this. I installed the ff_mpeg package several times - and like you said Kivy fails to recognize it. Thank you so much.